# How to do I tell Quicktime player to start a New Movie Recording with a apple script?

Tags: applescript, video, quicktime

I have made a duplicate of the application "Quicktime player" on my Mac and renamed it "Reaction" then I have put this copy inside of a applescript. I am trying to write a code that tells the "Reaction" to start a "New Movie Recording" (which is a option of recording) then save the recording within the applescript. (the name of the recording is irrelevant)

Extra: Also if anyone knows how I could then code a way to add the recording to a email and send it to people that would be great.

At the moment I know how to open "Reaction" but not how to tell "Reaction" to start a "New Movie Recording"

So far i'm using this to open "Reaction"

```
  set appPath1 to path to resource "Reaction.app"
tell application "Finder"


open appPath1

end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Having duplicated your *QuickTime Player* application and named it *Reaction*, I understand you've created an AppleScript applet, and placed this copy of *Reaction.app* within the `Resources` folder of the AppleScript applet.

Because it's a duplicate of *QuickTime Player* (which is scriptable), *Reaction* is also scriptable, and can also be scripted from within the applet's AppleScript (located at `Resources/scripts/main.scpt`).

Your `main.scpt` should look something like this:

```
set A to path to resource "Reaction.app"

set home to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
set fp to home & "/Movies/Reaction Recording.mov"
set f to a reference to POSIX file fp

using terms from application "QuickTime Player"
    tell the application named A
        activate
        tell the (new movie recording)
            start
            delay 10
            pause
            save in f
            stop
            close
        end tell
    end tell
end using terms from
```

`application "QuickTime Player"` may change of its own accord to `application "Reaction"`, which is completely fine.

This script creates a ~10 second recording, minus a couple of seconds to account for the initialisation of the script and such.  Change `delay 10` to whatever value represents a sensible recording time in seconds.

To send it as an attachment using *Mail*:

```
set msgSubject to "My Reaction Recording"
set msgBody to "Hi. Please see the attached recording. \n"
set msgFrom to "your@email.com"
set msgTo to "friend@email.com"

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    tell (make new outgoing message ¬
        with properties {visible:true ¬
        , subject:msgSubject ¬
        , content:msgBody ¬
        , sender:msgFrom})

        make new to recipient ¬
            at end of to recipients ¬
            with properties {address:msgTo}

        tell its content to make new attachment ¬
            at after the last paragraph ¬
            with properties {file name:f as alias}

        delay 2

        -- send
    end tell
end tell
```

The top script and the bottom script can simply join to form one continuous script.  You might need a delay in between the two portions, but I didn't require one on my system.

However, the delay within the *Mail* block is important if you wish to send the email (you must also uncomment the `send` command by removing the `--`; keeping it in, which I did during testing, will allow you to preview the email and send it manually).

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to post a better and more thorough answer! :)

Comment: Have a look at [path to (folder)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19) and you'll see that you can instead use `path to movies folder` and avoid unnecessary getting `path to home folder` first. Lines 2 and 3 get replaced by `set fp to POSIX path of (path to movies folder) & "Reaction Recording.mov"`, thus negating the need for line 2. Nice script otherwise. +1